# How to skip return value in function where value is expected

Tags: swift, return

This is the function I am using:

```
let values = (0..<self.data.count).map { (i) -> ChartDataEntry in
    let x = valueDate!.timeIntervalSince(startDate)
    if let a = (self.data[i]["labelvalue"] as? NSString)?.doubleValue{
        return ChartDataEntry(x: Double(x), y: a)
    } else {
        return nil
    }
}
```

This is causing this error:

> Nil is incompatible with return type 'ChartDataEntry'

How can I skip the loop without returning any value and continue with next check?

Comment: use compactMap instead.

Answer (score 2):

```
let values = (0..<self.data.count).compactMap { (i) -> ChartDataEntry? in
            let x = valueDate!.timeIntervalSince(startDate)
            if let a = (self.data[i]["labelvalue"] as? NSString)?.doubleValue{
                return ChartDataEntry(x: Double(x), y: a)
            }

            return nil
        }
```

Replace your code with this.

`compactMap` - Returns an array containing the non-nil results of calling the given transformation with each element of this sequence.

You can read more about `compactMap` [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/2957701-compactmap)

Comment: @sdd can u pls mark the answer if the answer is helpful to you? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the correct answer of Aakash to use `compactMap` this is a *swiftier* (and more efficient) version

- `x` is a constant, so create it **once** outside of the closure.
- `TimeInterval` is a type alias of `Double`, `Double(x)` is redundant.
- (Compact)map the `data` array, not its indices.
- Avoid unnecessary bridge casts.

---

```
let x = valueDate!.timeIntervalSince(startDate)
let values = self.data.compactMap { (item) -> ChartDataEntry? in
    guard let d = item["labelvalue"] as? String, let a = Double(d) else { return nil }
    return ChartDataEntry(x: x, y: a)
}
```